how to use std::uniform_int_distribution<>::operator()
How to use operator()(Generator& g, const param_type& params); of std::uniform_int_distribution. This is my code
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int get_random_int(const int lower_limit, const int upper_limit) {
   std::random_device rd{};
   std::mt19937 gen{rd()};

   static std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist;
   
   // use operator()(Generator& g, const param_type& params);
   return dist(gen, lower_limit, upper_limit);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << get_random_int(1, 1000000) << std::endl;
}


return dist(gen, {lower_limit, upper_limit}); should work.

In documentation there is an example. In fact IMO it is better set range of value in construction time.

@MarekR No example of using the second overload of operator().

Side note also make your generator and random device static (you don't want to restart then every call)

@Yksisarvinen I noticed that so already updated my comment

Random distribution objects may be stateful, the result of future operator() may depends on past calls to operator() to guarantee uniformity. By creating and destroying the distribution each time the function is called your results might not be entirely uniform.

You need to create an object of type param_type.
    return dist(gen, std::uniform_int_distribution<>::param_type{lower_limit, upper_limit});

You can shorten the name to decltype(dist)::param_type, though the syntax isn't much more readable in my opinion. Name alias would also make it shorter and cleaner.

Implicit construction with just {lower_limit, upper_limit} doesn't work: https://godbolt.org/z/4cr3f758K, although I don't see a requirement in cppreference that would mandate explicit constructor.

Also, note that the expensive part of the operation is setting up random number engine (here std::mt19937), not the distribution itself. It would be better (and easier) to make that static instead:
int get_random_int(const int lower_limit, const int upper_limit) {
    static std::random_device rd{};
    static std::mt19937 gen{rd()};
   
   return std::uniform_int_distribution{lower_limit, upper_limit}(gen);
}


A bit off topic, but your code has problems and the wrong thing is declared as static.

std::random_device is slow and is true random generator (if supported by platform) it should be used only once. When you use this multiple time then you do not need std::mt19937
std::mt19937 initialization is a bit costly. This is the thing you should make static.
std::uniform_int_distribution is simple thing it just holds range for which random values should be generated, so there is not point to hod this as static and is very cheep to create this on each call.

So I would fix your code this way:
int get_random_int(const int lower_limit, const int upper_limit)
{
    static std::mt19937 gen { std::random_device {}() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist { lower_limit, upper_limit };
    return dist(gen);
}

https://godbolt.org/z/oahEEoM9d
It doesn't look like think you ask for, but it does thing you need in less bulky way.
Version where only random device is used on each call: https://godbolt.org/z/96Yd51hz7
Here is demo how well compiler is able to optimize such code: https://godbolt.org/z/rP7vfMoW7 (code was trimmed so assembly is easier to read).
